# Auto trigger click button Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to auto click the "share-button" after page loading page. I have tried number 1 method but still cannot auto click. Number 2 is the original code. Currently still require me to manually click the share-button.

1.

This one using "window.onload" method.

```
 <div>
            
            <button id="share-button" onclick="autoClick()">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

function autoClick() {
FB.ui({
display: 'popup',
method: 'feed',
link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',

```
        }, function (response) {
            //Debug response (optional)
            console.log(response);

        });
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('share-button').click();
    }
```

2. 

```
<div id="buttons">
   
    <div>
        <button type="button" id="share-button">Continue</button>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'ID',
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v11.0'
        });
    };

    

    document.getElementById('share-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        FB.ui({
            display: 'popup',
            method: 'share',
            href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',

        }, function (response) {
            //Debug response (optional)
            console.log(response);
        });
    });

    //Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementsById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


</script>

<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Comment: You say you want to click on `share-button` but in your code you are trying to click on `auth-button`

Comment: Sorry, that is just example I try out. If I use the auth-button method but replace it with share button id still cannot auto click

Answer (score 0):

The approach is just wrong. Instead of "clicking" a button, you should write the listener in a separate function, and call that function instead.

Something like:

```
document.getElementById('share-button').addEventListener('click', share);

function share() {
        FB.ui({
            display: 'popup',
            method: 'share',
            href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',

        }, function (response) {
            //Debug response (optional)
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

So that you can do at any time, something like:

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        share();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it , but still cannot auto click. Do I need to declare share? Eg:  <div>
            <button type="button" id="share-button" onclick="share()">Share</button>
        </div>